# C# XML Serializing list with element name depending on class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to serialize a `List<AbstractClass>` that contains `DerivedClassA` and `DerivedClassB` where both of these classes are derived from `AbstractClass`.

Additionally I want to add an attribute to the element that wraps each element of the list. My desired output is something like this:

```
<MyCustomListName foo="bar">
    <DerivedClassA baseAttribute="value" attributeFromA="value"/>
    <DerivedClassB baseAttribute="value" attributeFromB="value"/>
    ...
</MyCustomListName>
```

What I have so far is this:

```
public class MyCustomListName
{
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string foo {get; set;}

   [XmlArray]        
   public List<AbstractClass> list { get; set; }

}

[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedClassA))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedClassB))]
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string baseAttribute {get; set;}
}

public class DerivedClassA : AbstractClass
{
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string attributeFromA {get; set;}
}

public class DerivedClassB : AbstractClass
{
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string attributeFromB {get; set;}
}
```

Using this, I get the following output:

```
<MyCustomListName foo="bar">
  <list>
    <AbstractClass xsi:type="DerivedClassA" baseAttribute="value" attributeFromA="value"/>
    <AbstractClass xsi:type="DerivedClassB" baseAttribute="value" attributeFromB="value"/>
  </list>
</MyCustomListName>
```

So, to get my desired output, there should be no nested `<list>` element and instead of the `xsi:type` attribute, the element name should be `DerivedClassA` or `DerivedClassB` depending on the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide different names for items of different types:

```
[XmlElement("derivedA", typeof(DerivedClassA))]
[XmlElement("derivedB", typeof(DerivedClassB))]
public List<AbstractClass> list { get; set; }
```

Comment: This seems to work for creating the proper element names. However, I would need to not output the `<list>` tag.