# XmlSerializer rename RootElement based on instance type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xmlserializer

I need to serialize object to XML.

I have an *abstract class* `CustomerAction`, and I need to translate the RootElement to *AddAction* or *CloseAction*.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(AddAction))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(CloseAction))]
public abstract class CustomerAction 
{
    public List<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}
```

What I have so far is :

```
<CustomerAction xsi:type="AddAction">
```

or

```
<CustomerAction xsi:type="CloseAction">
```

I would like to have :

`<AddAction>` or `<CloseAction>`

Is it possible to change the `RootElement` based on instance type ? I'm struggling to find how in the documentation.

Comment: do you have attributes  over the AddAction and CloseAction classes? try adding [XmlElement("CloseAction")] on them

Comment: Another thing to try, add  [XmlElement("CloseAction"), typeof(CloseAction)] and  same for AddAction over that CustomerAction

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan I can't add XmlElement over a `class`, it's only available on a property. My `CustomerAction` is used inside a _Customer_ class which has `List<CustomerAction>` property.

Comment: I don't think this is a supported scenario; I'm happy to be corrected, but...

Comment: Add that attributes over the list than, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676736/c-sharp-xml-serializing-list-with-element-name-depending-on-class

Comment: @MarcGravell I just figured out `[XmlArrayItem(typeof(AddAction))]` is working.

Comment: @Florian for the list? sure; but for the root element? pretty sure not

Comment: You could serialize each `CustomerAction` using a serializer constructed for its actual, concrete type, then for deserialization create serializers for each possible type and test each against the XML stream using `XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize(XmlReader)`.  See: [How to deserialize XML if the return type could be an Error or Success object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44248192/3744182).

Comment: @dbc I ended up implement ISerializer for custom serialization.